# ios react-native AFNetwoking client certificate authenification

Tags: c++, react-native, https, ssl-certificate, afnetworking

Be gladfull about any info about how to add client p12 certificate validation to this ssl pinning code. This is part of ssl pinning module for react-native.

```
#import "RNSslPinning.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@interface RNSslPinning()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig;

@end

@implementation RNSslPinning
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
        self.sessionConfig.HTTPCookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    }
    return self;
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getCookies: (NSURL *)url resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject){
    
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieJar  =  NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage;
    
    NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = @{}.mutableCopy;
    
    for (cookie in [cookieJar cookiesForURL:url]) {
        [dictionary setObject:cookie.value forKey:cookie.name];
    }
    
    if ([dictionary count] > 0){
        resolve(dictionary);
    }
    else{
        NSError *error = nil;
        reject(@"no_cookies", @"There were no cookies", error);
    }
}



RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(removeCookieByName: (NSString *)cookieName
                  resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieStorage.cookies) {
        // [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
        NSString * name = cookie.name;
        
        if([cookieName isEqualToString:name]) {
            [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
    
    resolve(nil);
    
}


-(void)performRequest:(AFURLSessionManager*)manager  obj:(NSDictionary *)obj  request:(NSMutableURLRequest*) request callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback  {
    
    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        
        
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSString *bodyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSInteger statusCode = httpResp.statusCode;
        
        if (!error) {
            // if(obj[@"responseType"]){
            NSString * responseType = obj[@"responseType"];
            
            if ([responseType isEqualToString:@"base64"]){
                NSString* base64String = [responseObject base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
                callback(@[[NSNull null], @{
                               @"status": @(statusCode),
                               @"headers": httpResp.allHeaderFields,
                               @"data": base64String
                }]);
            }
            else {
                callback(@[[NSNull null], @{
                               @"status": @(statusCode),
                               @"headers": httpResp.allHeaderFields,
                               @"bodyString": bodyString ? bodyString : @""
                }]);
            }
        } else if (error && error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey]) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(@[@{
                               @"status": @(statusCode),
                               @"headers": httpResp.allHeaderFields,
                               @"bodyString": bodyString ? bodyString : @""
                }, [NSNull null]]);
            });
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(@[error.localizedDescription, [NSNull null]]);
            });
        }
    }] resume];
    
}


-(void) setHeaders: (NSDictionary *)obj request:(NSMutableURLRequest*) request {
    
    if (obj[@"headers"] && [obj[@"headers"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *m = [obj[@"headers"] mutableCopy];
        for (NSString *key in [m allKeys]) {
            if (![m[key] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                m[key] = [m[key] stringValue];
            }
        }
        [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:m];
    }
    
}

- (BOOL) isFilePart: (NSArray*)part {
    if (![part[1] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSDictionary * value = part[1];
    return [value objectForKey:@"type"] && ([value objectForKey:@"name"] || [value objectForKey:@"fileName"]);
}

-(void) appendFormDataFilePart: (id<AFMultipartFormData>) formData fileData: (NSArray*) fileData  {
    NSString * key = fileData[0];
    NSDictionary * value = fileData[1];
    NSString * fileName = [value objectForKey:@"name"] ? [value objectForKey:@"name"] : [value objectForKey:@"fileName"];
    NSString * mimeType = [value objectForKey:@"type"];
    NSString * path = [value objectForKey:@"uri"] ? [value objectForKey:@"uri"] : [value objectForKey:@"path"];
    
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] name:key fileName:fileName mimeType:mimeType error:nil];
}

-(void) performMultipartRequest: (AFURLSessionManager*)manager obj:(NSDictionary *)obj url:(NSString *)url request:(NSMutableURLRequest*) request callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback formData:(NSDictionary*) formData {
    NSString * method = obj[@"method"] ? obj[@"method"] : @"POST";
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *formDataRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:method URLString:url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> _formData) {
        if([formData objectForKey:@"_parts"]){
            NSArray * parts = formData[@"_parts"];
            for (int i = 0; i < [parts count]; i++)
            {
                NSArray * part = parts[i];
                NSString * key = part[0];
                
                if ([self isFilePart:part]) {
                    [self appendFormDataFilePart:_formData fileData: part];
                } else {
                    NSString * value = part[1];
                    NSData *data = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    [_formData appendPartWithFormData:data name: key];
                }
            }
        }
    } error:nil];
    
    // Migrate header fields.
    [formDataRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[request allHTTPHeaderFields]];
    
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager
                                          uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:formDataRequest
                                          progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
        NSLog(@"Upload progress %lld", uploadProgress.completedUnitCount / uploadProgress.totalUnitCount);
    }
                                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSString *bodyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSInteger statusCode = httpResp.statusCode;
        if (!error) {
            
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            
            NSString *bodyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSInteger statusCode = httpResp.statusCode;
            
            NSDictionary *res = @{
                @"status": @(statusCode),
                @"headers": httpResp.allHeaderFields,
                @"bodyString": bodyString ? bodyString : @""
            };
            callback(@[[NSNull null], res]);
        }
        else if (error && error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey]) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(@[@{
                               @"status": @(statusCode),
                               @"headers": httpResp.allHeaderFields,
                               @"bodyString": bodyString ? bodyString : @""
                }, [NSNull null]]);
            });
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback(@[error.localizedDescription, [NSNull null]]);
            });
        }
    }];
    
    [uploadTask resume];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(fetch:(NSString *)url obj:(NSDictionary *)obj callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
    NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:u];
    
    AFSecurityPolicy *policy;
    BOOL pkPinning = [[obj objectForKey:@"pkPinning"] boolValue];
    BOOL disableAllSecurity = [[obj objectForKey:@"disableAllSecurity"] boolValue];
    
    NSSet *certificates = [AFSecurityPolicy certificatesInBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    
    // set policy (ssl pinning)
    if(disableAllSecurity){
        policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
        policy.validatesDomainName = false;
        policy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;
    }
    else if (pkPinning){
        policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey withPinnedCertificates:certificates];
    }
    else{
        policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate withPinnedCertificates:certificates];
    }
    
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.securityPolicy = policy;
    
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    
    
    if (obj[@"method"]) {
        [request setHTTPMethod:obj[@"method"]];
    }
    if (obj[@"timeoutInterval"]) {
        [request setTimeoutInterval:[obj[@"timeoutInterval"] doubleValue] / 1000];
    }
    
    if(obj[@"headers"]) {
        [self setHeaders:obj request:request];
    }
    
    if (obj) {
        
        if ([obj objectForKey:@"body"]) {
            NSDictionary * body = obj[@"body"];
            
            // this is a multipart form data request
            if([body isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                // post multipart
                if ([body objectForKey:@"formData"]) {
                    [self performMultipartRequest:manager obj:obj url:url request:request callback:callback formData:body[@"formData"]];
                } else if ([body objectForKey:@"_parts"]) {
                    [self performMultipartRequest:manager obj:obj url:url request:request callback:callback formData:body];
                }
            }
            else {
                
                // post a string
                NSData *data = [obj[@"body"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [request setHTTPBody:data];
                [self performRequest:manager obj:obj request:request callback:callback ];
                //TODO: if no body
            }
            
        }
        else {
            [self performRequest:manager obj:obj request:request callback:callback ];
        }
    }
    else {
        
    }
    
}

+ (BOOL)requiresMainQueueSetup
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

All info, I've had found, is about to create some challenge to session and send client certificate with password from there.
But not sure how to implement this right way. And can't figure which version of AFNetworking used in this SSL Pinning module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.
In "fetch" function, after "manager" decloration, use this code:

```
[manager setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * _Nonnull challenge, NSURLCredential *__autoreleasing  _Nullable * _Nullable credential) {
    
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        SecTrustResultType result;
        SecTrustEvaluate(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, &result);
            
           // If we want to ignore invalid server for certificates, we just accept the server
        if (result == kSecTrustResultProceed || result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified) {
                // When testing this against a trusted server I got kSecTrustResultUnspecified every time. But the other two match the description of a trusted server
                
            *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        }
            
        return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
    }
    if ([[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate) {
        SecIdentityRef identity = NULL;
        SecTrustRef trust = NULL;
        NSString *p12 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"client"ofType:@"p12"];  //client cert
        NSData *PKCS12Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:p12];
        
        OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;
        NSDictionary*optionsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"password" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];   //client cert password
        CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
        securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data,(__bridge CFDictionaryRef)optionsDictionary,&items);
        if(securityError == 0) {
            CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust =CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items,0);
            const void*tempIdentity =NULL;
            tempIdentity= CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust,kSecImportItemIdentity);
            identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
            const void*tempTrust =NULL;
            tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust,kSecImportItemTrust);
            trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
        }
        
        SecCertificateRef certificate = NULL;
        SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate);
        const void*certs[] = {certificate};
        CFArrayRef certArray =CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, certs,1,NULL);
        *credential =[NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity certificates:(__bridge  NSArray*)certArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
        return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
    }
    return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge;
}];
```